# cascadeType.REMOVE not working(JPA spring data)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is my code. I want to delete all the records of tracking_event when i delete tracking table record which are in oneToMany relationship

> **Tracking** entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRACKING")
public class Tracking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TRACKING_ID")
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tracking",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<TrackingEvent> trackingEvents;
}
```

> **TrackingEvent** entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRACKING_EVENT")
public class TrackingEvent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TRACKING_EVENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRACKING_ID")
    private Tracking tracking;
}
```

> **TrackingRepository** interface

```
public interface TrackingRepository extends CrudRepository<Tracking, Integer> {
  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query(" DELETE FROM Tracking WHERE id = :tid")
  void deleteByUpdatedDate(@Param("tid") int tid);
}
```

I also tried using

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tracking",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TrackingEvent> trackingEvents;`
```

Comment: add the implementation of removal

Comment: which is where you look in the LOG at what is happening, with reference to whatever code calls `em.remove` and what object is passed in to it.

Comment: this is implementation of removal of parent object 
`@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("  DELETE FROM Tracking WHERE id = :tid")
void deleteByUpdatedDate(@Param("tid") int tid);`

Comment: @NeilStockton nothing comes in log. log is usefull only when some exception occurs

Comment: LOG is useful for ALL situations because when you set it to DEBUG level you can see WHAT is happening. aka debugging!

Comment: Executing a delete query manually like posted bypasses the ORM, which is why the delete is not being cascaded to the associated entities. If you want to stick to manual deletion, put a cascade to the associated table on the database side. This will ensure that the delete on the master table gets cascaded by the database to the associated table.